# 3 text boxes and a calculate button

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.6

I have 3 text boxes and a calculate button, how can i tell the button witch text box is selected and convert the number into other text boxes,  I have tagged the text boxes 1, 2 and 3, I am very new and green in programming so any help would be great.
This is my code

```
- (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    float a = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:_Barrels.text] floatValue];
    float b = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:_Gallons.text] floatValue];
    float c = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:_Liters.text] floatValue];


    _Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a];
    _Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a * 42];
    _Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a * 159];

    _Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b * .0238];
    _Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b];
    _Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b * 3.785];

    _Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c * .0063];
    _Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c * .264];
    _Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c];

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 1:
            [_Barrels resignFirstResponder];
            [_Gallons resignFirstResponder];
            [_Liters resignFirstResponder];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a variable/flag in the ViewController.h file  to store the last selected textfield

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    int textfieldFlag;
}

@end
```

in the ViewController.m file implement the textfieldDelegate Method

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{     
    textfieldFlag=textField.tag;
}
```

then in ur

```
 - (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender
{
   //ABove Code....   

    if(textfieldFlag==1){
    _Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a];
    _Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a * 42];
    _Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", a * 159];
   }
if(textfieldFlag==2){
    _Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b * .0238];
    _Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b];
    _Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", b * 3.785];
   }
if(textfieldFlag==3){
    _Barrels.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c * .0063];
    _Gallons.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c * .264];
    _Liters.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"% .2f", c];
   }

   //Below Code...
```

}

use the `textfieldFlag` accordingly.

`textfieldFlag` will contain the flag for the last textfield selected/edited

Comment: Is there any chance that you could set this in my code so I can see it, I am just getting a lot of errors here :/

Comment: sorry about the messy answer

Comment: oops my bad.. int textField = 0; in the .h is wrong, look at the edited answer

Comment: Ok, it is running now but if I put a number in 1 of the text boxes and hit calculate nothing comes in the other text boxes, any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: check if you have set the delegate for the textfields, and the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method is being called.

Comment: This is in my .m - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textFieldFlag=textField.tag;
}
This is in my .h interface VolumeViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: Have you any idea what it could be

Answer (score 0):

When you tap the Calculate button, this method must be called : `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`. Here, identify which textfield you editted by checking the tagValue, according to that, do the calculation. Make sure to add the delegates of the textfields otherwise - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing will not get called.